# MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler and the session token expiring between application restarts

Tags: wif, claims-based-identity

In my MVC application, I am using forms authentication to authenticate the user and then `System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule` to persist the session.

While I'm not yet at the point where it's necessary, I did want to utilize `System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler` so that the application will live nicely on a web farm (as described by Dominick Baier [here](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/07/12/machinekey-based-session-protection-for-wif/)).

The problem I have is that, given the machineKey-based handling, I would expect that not only would the session be valid from server machine to machine, but should also survive application restarts.  However, any time I either restart or rebuild the application, upon hitting the application in the browser, the cookie apparently becomes invalid and I get bounced to the authentication screen.  Once authenticated again, everything is fine and the session remains.  However, the next time the app restarts or is rebuilt, I'm forced to re-authenticate.

I'm sure this is an aspect of WIF that I'm not getting, but I just don't know where to turn from here.  I'm not afraid of having to extend `MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler`, but I'd like to make sure that I understand what's going on here before I proceed.    I understand that the default `SessionSecurityTokenHandler` uses DPAPI in combination with some identifier from the app pool for its cryptography, so it makes sense that this would happen in that case, but the behavior in `MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler` puzzles me.  Is there still some identifier in the application that gets recreated on restart on which `MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler` depends?  Am I just missing a setting?

Here are the pertinent parts from my web.config:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="system.identityModel"
           type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
</configSections>
```

...

```
<system.identityModel>
  <identityConfiguration>
    <securityTokenHandlers>
      <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </securityTokenHandlers>
  </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

...

```
<system.web>
  <machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework45"
              validationKey="E27893..."
              decryptionKey="ABC..." 
              validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
  <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login"
         timeout="10080" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

...

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule"
         type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Chris, just wanted to drop you a word of thanks. I was struggling trying to get something like this working for what I'm doing now, and the problem I had was getting the values in my web.configs right. So thanks for posting the web.config settings, b/c it just helped me solve this problem. Mike

Comment: Just thought I would pipe in that if you are using the SessionAuthenticationModule to authenticate users without using forms authentication you need a final piece past this to implement shared WIF caching (e.g. doesn't reset on app pool resets).  And that is a SessionSecurityTokenCache.  An example of one on the MSDN is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545457(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this was my stupid fault.  For reasons that are not pertinent here, I set the FedAuth cookie name to something non-standard (i.e. not "`FedAuth`"), like this:

```
FederatedAuthentication
  .FederationConfiguration
  .CookieHandler
  .Name = "SomeThingNotStandard";
```

The problem was I was setting it like this only at the moment that I issued the token on a successful login.  Well, of course everything's gonna be fine because now the in-memory configuration is looking for "SomeThingNotStandard" as the cookie name.  But, on an app restart, the configuration will be back to the default, looking for "`FedAuth`", not "`SomeThingNotStandard`".  This forces the re-login, which upon success, re-configures the app and then everything seems fine.

So I put the code bit above in `Application_Start()` and it works fine across re-builds and re-starts.

Dumb move on my part.

**Edit:**

I moved this to configuration

```
<system.identityModel.services>
  <federationConfiguration>
    <cookieHandler
      name="SomeThingNotStandard" />
  </federationConfiguration>
</system.identityModel.services>
```

Comment: I dont see how you could have gotten this to work. WIF defaults to an IN-MEMORY session token cache which would come in to play with the configuration you specified above. Open up SessionSecurityTokenCache in reflector and youll see what i mean[http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Claims-Aware-Web-Farm-088a7a4f] If the cache is in memory it will lose its marbles on app recycle. I implemented this using a custom SessionSecurityTokenCache to survive recycles.

Comment: @pete_w - The problem I presented was specifically about he cookie handler, not the cache.  Indeed, the default token cache is in-memory and an app recycle essentially wipes it out.  Like you, I ended up rolling my own custom caching solution to solve that problem.  However, _this_ problem was simply due to me setting a custom name for the token cookie in a bad place.  Two separate issues, really.

Answer (score 2):

hm - if you are setting the machine key explicitly (like you seem to do) - I don't see a reason why this would not work. Maybe you are using other cookies, sessions etc that trigger the re-auth problem?

Comment: Ugh, I found the issue.  This was just dumb on my part, due to setting the Fedauth cookie name to something custom, but in a bad place.  I'll post the answer below.